# Android: Firebase number increment

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I stuck at making an icrement of a value in Java with Firebase and the thing is it doesn't update a global variable. When I call an EventListener at onStart it successfully displays me the correct value of the variable(60). And when I want to increase it by 10 - with a button click - it displays me 0.

```
long value;

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    final TextView mValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.some_textview);

    mRef = new Firebase(some_correct_url);
    mRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            value = (long) dataSnapshot.getValue();
            mValue.setText(value+"");
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

And when a button is clicked the following function is being called

```
public void addTen(View view) {
    mRef = new Firebase(my_private_url);
    mRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            value =(long) dataSnapshot.getValue();
            value = value + 10;
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
        }
    });

    mRef.setValue(value);

}
```

So all in all the first part retrieves the correct value of the variable but the second part doesn't increase the correct value. Thanks in advance!

Edit: By the way I set the Firebase-rules as following:

```
{
"rules": {
".read": "true",
".write": "true"
}
}
```

This is for the development time.

Comment: what do u mean  **doesn't increase** did u print a Log or update value to UI  ?

Comment: Yes I was debugging the value of it and in the first part at onStart it appears to be correct but in the second part in the addTen function it takes the global initialization with zero value

Comment: It increases but starting with the wrong value. It starts at zero but it should start at 60(the value from firebase)

Comment: Maybe this was resolved here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44102312/how-to-increment-number-in-firebase

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firebase listeners fire asynchronously. Your call to `mRef.setValue(value)` executes before the listener has fired and updated `value`.  Change your code like this:

```
public void addTen(View view) {
    mRef = new Firebase(my_private_url);
    mRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            value =(long) dataSnapshot.getValue();
            value = value + 10;
            dataSnapshot.getRef().setValue(value);
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
        }
    });
}
```

Note that `addListenerForSingleValueEvent()` replaced `addValueEventListener()`.  I don't think you want to be stacking up listeners everytime `addten()` is called.

Comment: It still starts the increment at 0, but I see what you mean

Comment: @MichaelJancen-Widmer: For your posting, you replaced the real URLs with `some_correct_url` and `my_private_url`.  Are you sure the real URLs  are identical?

Comment: Yes they are, this was just for privacy

Comment: So, it sounds like the listener in `onStart()` returns 60, and the listener in `addTen()` on the same location returns 0.  I'm stumped.

Comment: Exactly. I actually think that it gets the 60 at addTen() but it doesn't return the value to the global variable "value". That's my guess.

Comment: Add some `Log` statements to get a better understanding of what's going on.

Comment: Thanks your answer worked after building the .apk and dragging it onto my device and installing there. I have run the app over an Emulator and it didn't work there. Anyway thanks a lot! :)

Comment: @qbix does this work as a transaction - or does it need to be altered to allow for update to not replace the value someone else is adding?

Answer (score 0):

in firestore you can increment value using this below method (you can reduce method)

```
void updateIMEICount(){
    progressDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.verifying_imei_dialog_message));
    progressDialog.show();

    firebaseFirestore.collection(Constants.FB_IMEI_ROOT_PATH).document("IMEI").get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = task.getResult();
                        final IMEIModel imeiModel = documentSnapshot.toObject(IMEIModel.class);
                        Log.d(TAG, "documentSnapshot imeiModel : " + imeiModel.toString());
                        final IMEIModel imeiModelUpdate = new IMEIModel();
                        imeiModelUpdate.setIMEI(imeiModel.getIMEI()+1);
                        documentSnapshot.getReference().set(imeiModelUpdate).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                progressDialog.dismiss();
                                Log.d(TAG,"imeiModelUpdate updated from : "+imeiModel.getIMEI());
                                Log.d(TAG,"imeiModelUpdate updated to : "+imeiModelUpdate.getIMEI());
                                launchHomeScreen();
                            }
                        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                progressDialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });

                        progressDialog.dismiss();

                    } else {
                        utility.failureToast("getting call id failed .please try again");
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Log.d(TAG, "getting getCallID failed");
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer has a correct mark is work but what happen if two user make same action in **same time** ?

Refer to [Save data as transactions in fire base](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions)

When working with data that could be corrupted by concurrent modifications, such as incremental counters, you can use a transaction operation.

For instance, in the example social blogging app, you could allow users to star and unstar posts and keep track of how many stars a post has received as follows:

```
private void onStarClicked(DatabaseReference postRef) {
    postRef.runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
        @Override
        public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
            Post p = mutableData.getValue(Post.class);
            if (p == null) {
                return Transaction.success(mutableData);
            }

            if (p.stars.containsKey(getUid())) {
                // Unstar the post and remove self from stars
                p.starCount = p.starCount - 1;
                p.stars.remove(getUid());
            } else {
                // Star the post and add self to stars
                p.starCount = p.starCount + 1;
                p.stars.put(getUid(), true);
            }

            // Set value and report transaction success
            mutableData.setValue(p);
            return Transaction.success(mutableData);
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b,
                               DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // Transaction completed
            Log.d(TAG, "postTransaction:onComplete:" + databaseError);
        }
    });
}
```

SO your way could be corrupted by concurrent modifications by two users add your value in same time