# How to increment number in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've edited the code. It works. It increment the counter in firebase. But there is 1 problem. Whenever I restart the app (after clear recent app), the increment starts over. It does not continue from previous number.

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
Button bNext;
long count;

DatabaseReference mRootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference mCounterRef = mRootRef.child("counter");

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    bNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bNext);

    bNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mCounterRef.setValue(++count);
        }
    });

}
}
```

[this is my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4ICA.png)

Comment: If the app crashes, please add the logcat to your question

Comment: the apk can be build. after install & click on the button (bNext) it crashed.

Comment: Again, add the logcat that tells us why the app crashes

Comment: A educated guess is that you don't have permission to write the data; a fact you conveniently hide by not handling `onCancelled()`. See http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/firebase/5548/how-do-i-listen-for-errors-when-accessing-the-database/22652/detect-errors-when-reading-data-on-android#t=201705220009247420929 
After fixing that problem, 
you'll also want to look at using Firebase transactions fo increment the counter: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions

Comment: The `count` variable is always 0 with your edit, you were closer with the previous version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three things require fixing:

1. `count` in your DB is a number and will be read as a `Long`.  You cannot cast directly to `int`.  Instead you can cast to a `long`, or you could use two casts: `int count = (int)(long) ...`
2. You are using the post-increment operator.  It adds one *after* using the value.  Use pre-increment instead.
3. Listen for a single change, otherwise you will loop, because `setValue()` will cause the listener for fire again, and again, etc.

As Frank notes, a [Transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions) is the better way to safely modify counters.

```
    final DatabaseReference mRootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    final DatabaseReference mCounterRef = mRootRef.child("counter");
    // listen for single change
    mCounterRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // getValue() returns Long
            long count = (long) dataSnapshot.child("count").getValue();

            System.out.println("count before setValue()=" + count);

            mCounterRef.child("count").setValue(++count);  // <= Change to ++count

            System.out.println("count after setValue()=" + count);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            // throw an error if setValue() is rejected
            throw databaseError.toException();
        }
    });
```

**Update for edited question:**

You probably need to update your security rules to allow write access. Add a completion listener to see if `setValue()` is failing:

```
mCounterRef.child("count").setValue(++count, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError,
                           DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
        if (databaseError != null) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + databaseError.getMessage());
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: hello, i have edited the question. but still 1 problem. the increment restart when app restart. any suggestion?

Comment: I updated my answer.  I can only guess what the problem is.  When you need help with a crash, it's important to include in your post the logcat output or at least the exception or error message is that is output when the crash occurs.